# バリデーションのエラーメッセージが表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, バリデーション

バリデーションに失敗した時メッセージを指したいのですが、editアクションは問題なくエラーメッセージが出るのですが、crateアクションの時のみエラーメッセージが出ません。何かわかる方教えていただきたいです。

調べたとろ,local:trueに問題がある方が多かったみたいですが、見たところ問題のないように見えました。

### view

```
 <%= form_with(model: @circle, local: true) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/circle_error' %>
      <%= f.label :名前 %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.label :応募資格 %>
      <%= f.text_field :qualification, class: 'form-
      <%= f.submit "作成", class: "btn btn-warning" %>
    <% end %>
```

### コントローラー

```
def new
    @circle = Circle.new
  end
  
  def create
      @circle = Circle.new(circle_params)
      @circle.owner = current_user
  if  @circle.save!
      @circle_user = CircleUser.new(circle_id: @circle.id, user_id: current_user.id)
      @circle_user.save!
      flash[:success] = "作成しました"
      redirect_to root_url
  else
      render 'new'
  end
  end
  
  def show
    @circle = Circle.find(params[:id])
    @apply = Apply.find_by(@apply)
    @circle_user = CircleUser.find_by(circle: @circle, user: current_user)
  end
  
  def edit
     @circle = Circle.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def update
    @circle = Circle.find(params[:id])
    if @circle.update(circle_params)
      flash[:success] = "サークル情報が更新されました"
      redirect_to @circle
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

### /app/views/shared/_circle_error.html.erb

```
<% if @circle.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      入力エラーが <%= pluralize(@circle.errors.count, "件ありました") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @circle.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

解決方法がわかりました。原因はsave!の!をつけているのが原因でした。